# Is there any use for an old iPad

Tags: ipados

I have an ancient iPad 4 with iOS 10.3.3. In terms of hardware, it is still sufficient for my needs, as I use it primarily to project files, web pages and videos during lectures. But using it is becoming more and more annoying. There are fewer and fewer programs that can be installed, and sometimes I just have to install something. Recently, I looked for an app compatible with KeePass and found none.

Is there any hope for continued use? For example, would jailbreaking help to get older versions of the software? Or should I just give up and buy something else?

P.S. Neither I nor anyone in my family possesses newer iOS device.

Comment: I don't think this is really answerable. What do you want to do with it? Play the latest games - not gonna happen. Browse the web - until protocols change far enough to prevent it. Download apps - if there's still an older version available, yes, it will let you do that. Read books - pretty much forever. I still use my iPad mini rev1 [iOS 9]for that.

Answer (score 2):

When devices are new/popular there is a symbiotic relationship:

- When there are lots of devices it is worth developers building apps for them.
- When there are lots of apps its worth users buying the device.

It's unlikely that if you go off the beaten path you will find as active an eco-system as that of a new device.

That said if you buy a new device and reset the old one (clear any private data) you will probably find other uses for the old device - even if its just simple web browsing, note taking or setting alarms/reminders.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably still useful for viewing PDFs, ebooks, audio, video, and the occasional website; (though modern web standards may be beyond it).

I would accept that it's got some life as a content viewer; but not much more than that.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that if you want to use newer apps you'll likely need a newer device.

I have an original iPad Air that is no longer getting iPadOS updates. I use the app [Touch Portal](https://www.touch-portal.com) as my "bunch of buttons" device (ala Stream Deck), to launch applications and automations on my Mac. It supports devices running iOS 9.3 or higher.

I have a 3rd generation iPad Pro for my regular iPad use.